# Custom decrypt: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

### Issue

I am currently experiencing an issue where I am getting the following error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` which is happening on the line that is outlined below in the code section.

It seems to happen when I try to decrypt a bunch of data that is returned from my API as the error is being thrown in the service I have created.

Strange thing being is that when I call the method on data that is smaller it works without an issue. The `ApiService` that is mentioned below has its decrypt method outlined below under the code section, this is the part that is specifically causing the error.

Hope you guys can help out with this because it is quite strange that it works for smaller amounts of data but not larger amounts.

---

### Stack Trace

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at ApiService.<anonymous> (api.service.ts:167)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:97)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:78)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:68)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17298)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at zone.js:889
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at zone.js:741
    at rejected (tslib.es6.js:69)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17298)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at zone.js:889
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17289)
```

---

### Data

The data that is being passed on to the below outlined methods is as follows:

```
Data: "PHAl4fGtOUPM9Rop5P0eG1f1L9kx1HQXi5WfZ2jIFakznGLwzl......"
IV: "AM+Ljm3np1XL+1SiM4IfM+pNx21zQ4q4XnK9DKoN3ZCWKV5CWt62z/myCEZt9e66g/wxC/Jeq1q6yTEaT0AIrwE8ek9OWGWCCFAOttmbYli+SCYzUf3yW0NrcQR3nerpbbXqGjQA4LnNbwm26vQ42AuWhRbK2V7MP0aN4E68NUMGVs+mOjaX6QbZ50wvILSTK0O/y/P2AYiHhXrWPlDajVy8kZ65m4qnPKbDnwzp5lK37fXs9jwwcUUUYW+9jQh4qVkOaQNKvUTZu5BqmDz8/A80B+Q9rt4hy3EdCphWM8bfJ7RE3/W8S/EVUcuElqpsvB6XkBy9Q+VbtjlotZcnnw=="
Key: "ngOW45g78VaMAAzbWPol9y99lTnjtNylAKstkZF2jWoXq3SQI5Vd+yS2/vNkdtat0BxI+UHKNL98IvvCf3JIYLAfpzFhRjBWCZwo2RZms4OJMwngItPGTFc9cHtSMbTNI5FlXMciJrrA+yj5HWZ3kcpVYn3d8tiXpGEVgEorxdxijhim9vsgXbXS5ZG39KwW2mxOMMiFdd/UbMZLC01zNpE5t8DmYNoMUmCva1Y6cDuZEt8DYM3z4rXLTd2EefnFuX/DcXiD9CKqMyw2bBmIFouv+qDVbnQ/bR5mjLGW/rC7TNELOU2Y/VFf+26wZe2u0C7MRsf9wAbcxPC6UAocAQ=="
```

---

### Code

The line I am getting the error on is as follows:

```
return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(decryptedData));
```

And the entire method that the error is being thrown in is as follows:

```
//Method that will decrypt the data being received

  private async decryptData(data: any): Promise<any> {
    //Get the client private key from storage
    let clientPrivateKey = localStorage.getItem(AppSettings.PRIVATE_KEY);

    //Deserialize the JSON
    let response = data;

    //Get the buffer of the IV
    let ivBuffer = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(response.IV);

    //Get the private key in CryptoKey format
    let importedPrivateKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "pkcs8",
      this.base64ToArrayBuffer(clientPrivateKey),
      {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        hash: { name: "SHA-256" }
      },
      false,
      ["decrypt"]
    );
    //Get the bytes of the IV
    let ivBytes = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
      },
      importedPrivateKey,
      ivBuffer
    );

    //Take IV to text
    let ivArr = new Uint8Array(ivBytes);
    let IV = this.Utf8ArrayToStr(ivArr);

    //Get the buffer of the key
    let keyBuffer = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(response.Key);
    //Decrypt the key
    let keyBytes = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      {
        name: "RSA-OAEP"
      },
      importedPrivateKey,
      keyBuffer
    );
    //Take the key to text
    let keyArr = new Uint8Array(keyBytes);
    let key = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "raw", //can be "jwk" or "raw"
      keyArr,
      "AES-CBC",
      false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
      ["encrypt", "decrypt"] //can be "encrypt", "decrypt", "wrapKey", or "unwrapKey"
    )

    //Take from B64 to bytes then decrypt
    let responseData = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(response.Data);
    //Decrypt the actual data
    //let decryptedData = await this.aes.decrypt(key, IV, responseData);
    let decryptedData = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      {
        name: "AES-CBC",
        iv: ivArr, //The initialization vector you used to encrypt
      },
      key, //from generateKey or importKey above
      responseData //ArrayBuffer of the data
    )

    //Return the decrypted data for use
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(decryptedData));
  }
```

The Base64 helper methods are as follows:

```
private arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
  }

  private base64ToArrayBuffer(b64) {
    var byteString = window.atob(b64);
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      byteArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return byteArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the way I do the decoding of the `ArrayBuffer` to a string.

I replaced the following:

```
return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(decryptedData));
```

With:

```
return new Uint8Array(decryptedData).reduce(function (data, byte) {
      return data + String.fromCharCode(byte);
    }, '');
```

Comment: This probably saved me a few hours :-), tx